# PC loading programs slower than normal after voltage change

Tags: performance, voltage

I always turned on my PC at 220V, it always worked normally. Today I turned my PC at 110V and it was very slow to load any program. I turned it back on at 220V but it is still very low to load anything.

Changing the voltage could have changed some configuration on my PC? What could have happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: Just to clarify - did the system get moved between a 220V source to a 110V source and back?  Or did you simply flip the switch?  What is the power actually coming out of the wall?

Comment: Running at 220V. Turn off. Turn on at 110V. Turn off. Turn on at 220V.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you live in America or Canada the switch should be on 110v. If you live in Europe or any other country in that area, they use 220v. But if you flipped it to a voltage its not supposed to be at, there is a possibility that you can fry or shock a part inside of your computer or ruin it.

[image: Computer PSU with voltage switch and warning label]

Comment: Yes, if you literally just flipped the switch (*why?*) you may have damaged something.  Probably a hard drive, judging from slowdowns.